# ReactJS How to fetch only if a condition is true?

Tags: reactjs, api-hook

I'm trying to find a proper way to use `useFecthApi` conditionnally.

I have the following component :

```js
export const DetailedUser: FC = () => {
  const userState = useFetchApi(() => findUser(userId))

  const fetchContacts = mustFecthContacts() // implemenattion does not matter
  return (
    <>
       <UserInformation userState={userState } />
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
type Props = Readonly<{
  userState: State<UserDetails>
}>

export const UserInformation : FC<Props> = ({ userState }) => {

}
```

What I would like to do, is to create a `contactState` defined by `const contactState= useFetchApi(() => findContacts(userId))` only if `fetchContacts` equals `true`, and then pass this `contactState` to `UserInformation`.

So basically, something like :

```js
export const DetailedUser: FC = () => {
  const userState = useFetchApi(() => findUser(userId))
  // fetchContacts is a boolean (implementation is not important)
  const fetchContacts = mustFecthContacts()

  const contactStates = fetchContacts ? useFetchApi(() => findContacts(userId)) : undefined
  return (
    <>
       <UserInformation userState={userState} contactsState = {contactStates } />
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
type Props = Readonly<{
  userState: State<UserDetails>,
  contactStates? : State<ContactDetails>
}>

export const UserInformation : FC<Props> = ({ userState, contactStates }) => {

}
```

I'm pretty new to react (and to frond en development) so I don't know how to achieve that properly.
Any advice ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `useEffect` hook to fetch data. And also `useState` to store the data locally in a component.

Something like:

```
// this stores the userState properly
const [userState, setUserState] = useState(() => {
  return useFetchApi(() => findContacts(userId))
});

// this triggers everytime fetchContacts changes and will
// fetch new data if fetchContacts is "truthy"
useEffect(() => {
  if(!!fetchContacts) {
    const userData = useFetchApi(() => findContacts(userId))
    setUserState(userData)
  }
}, [fetchContacts])
```

Comment: It's a way to convert the value into its boolean representation, it's called double-bang operator.
So truthy values equal to `true` and rest will be `false`. You can even omit the `!!` and the condition will work, but in my opinion, it makes things more readable.